# CRMAP7009 : CCRC Command "RemoveResource" failed - Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have created a view in ClearCase in which I have worked for sometime and then I was getting some issues in checkin and checkout afterwards so I have deleted that view and created new one which is working fine.

But now sudden I got to know that there are some files added to the source control which are reflecting and not required.

Issue: I went to clear team Navigator -> In sub stream Activities.
There I can see the activity that I committed.
On right click on activity, I can see only options: Remove Activity, Check in (which I cannot do), Disconnect, Show change set, refresh, remove properties.

Now when I trying to remove that activity it is giving an error:

```
CRMAP7009 : CCRC Command "RemoveResource" failed
```

I cannot share screenshots because it is restricted.

Does anyone having idea, how can I remove the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you still have checked out files, but in a view that has been since deleted.

See if an admin can make sure your view is fully unregistered and remove for all vobs, which would make those files *not* checked out anymore.

See "[Manually remove Web views for CCRC and CCWeb](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21172246)" (CC 7.x but could apply to 8 or 9), which involves:

```
cleartool rmview -uuid <uuid> -all
cleartool unregister -view -uuid <uuid>
```

Once those files are not checked out anymore, the activity will be empty, and you will be able to delete it.

---

The [OP AIM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5001758/aim)  confirms [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671020/crmap7009-ccrc-command-removeresource-failed-clearcase/37671178#comment64151088_37671178):

> we did not able to clear view from my end.
>   So admin went to the server and clear the views and the left checkouts and that helped

The way an admin would have clean this view on the server side is by running those same commands I mention above.

Comment: Thanks. I have given the solution to Admin. They are working on it.

Comment: @AIM Great, let me know if they find any other solution.

Comment: Finally we did not able to clear view from my end. So admin went to the server and clear the views and the left checkouts and that helped. :)

Comment: @AIM Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks VonC for the support :)